# Zsh or Bash: Pass all command output through pager like app automatically?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

Is there a way in bash or zsh to automatically pipe all output from any commands I run through another program?

For example, if I ran this command

```
$ cat /tmp/it
```

I'd like it to run like I had written it like so:

```
$ cat /tmp/it | tee /tmp/cmdoutput
```

where the `| tee /tmp/cmdoutput` part could be any command at all. My use cases are for colorization and for saving output for commands I run so I can edit them in vim, or search them in vim. I do these things already manually but want to know if there's a way to do this automatically, and am looking for a general solution!

Comment: Do you need the command you typed in your output file?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in having any command I run, no matter what, stored in a temporary file somewhere - so if I want to review the output of any command I ran at any point today for example, I could look in a temp folder that had that had my commands stored with a time stamp, and the output there as well. Kind of a rolling log of what I'm doing at the command line. But the colorization idea is another thing I might like to use this process for as well, without having to manually pipe or alias certain commands.

Comment: I advise to look at [auditd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd). Otherwise a raw output of commands of an interractive session can simply be done with `bash | tee /tmp/cmdoutput`

Comment: Another alternative might be [script](https://linux.die.net/man/1/script).

Comment: How about adding an alias for the commands you mostly use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the
[script command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) :

> script makes a typescript of everything displayed on your terminal. It
>   is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive
>   session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be
>   printed out later with lpr(1).
>
> If the argument file is given, script saves the dialogue in this file.
>   If no filename is given, the dialogue is saved in the file typescript.

When you are ready to start recording a log file, type:

```
script /tmp/cmdoutput
```

Now, until you stop the script, **all input and output** in the Terminal will be stored in `cmdoutput`. When you are done, just type:

```
exit
```

**Source:** [How do I log all input and output in a terminal session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session)